# Python empty constructor

Tags: python, initialization, default

Is there any way to create an empty constructor in python. I have a class:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

now I initialize it like this:

```
p = Point(0, 5, 10)
```

How can I create an empty constructor and initialize it like this:

```
p = Point()
```

Comment: And what should the x, y and z of the second version be? Don't you just want default arguments? Have you tried reading a tutorial or doing some research?

Answer (score 52):

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: But this cannot coexist with the current implementation. Only one method with that name will be retained.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: In place of "pass", "1" also would have worked, or any null operation.  See more: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html

Answer (score 26):

As @jonrsharpe said in comments, you can use the default arguments.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Now you can call `Point()`

Comment: This works, but be careful. Passing over any mutable types (objects, arrays...) will make it shared between all instances.

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve your desired results by constructing the class in a slightly different manner.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def setvalues(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Comment: Shouldn't `setvalues` take 'self' as the first argument? Also, shouldn't all those instance variables be defined in `__init__`?

Comment: @RCross yeah it should have self as the first arg, edited to reflect. The constructor wouldn't be empty if we had instance variable declarations in it however. I agree that it isn't pythonic however.

Answer (score 12):

You should define the `__init__()` method of your `Point` class with optional parameters.

In your case, this should work:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, z=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

pointA = Point(0, 5, 10)
print("pointA: x={}, y={}, z={}".format(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointA.z))
# print "pointA: x=0, y=5, z=10"

pointB = Point()
print("pointB: x={}, y={}, z={}".format(pointB.x, pointB.y, pointB.z))
# print "pointB: x=0, y=0, z=0"
```

Comment: This is the best answer. It covers all of the ground that the original question asks about.